# Etch a Sketch - Mouseover color change doesn't work after changing div content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Purpose of the exercise is to create grids of select dimensions, and for individual grid to change color whenever mouse hovers on it.

The original grid changes color as intended whenever mouse hovers on it. But my problem is that when I create new grids, the mouseover color change no longer works.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--gridRows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--gridColumns', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = 'grid-item'
  }
}

makeGrid(6, 6);

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let side = prompt('Enter # of squares per side');
  container.replaceChildren();
  makeGrid(side, side);
});

const item = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
item.forEach((cell) => {
  cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    cell.style.background = 'blue';
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--gridRows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gridColumns), 1fr);
  width: 960px;
  height: 960px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
}

#form {
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Project Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="form">Enter number of squares per side for the new grid: </button>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item')` and the loop adding event listeners only runs on the first load. You'll need to run those again after you update the DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the part of attaching mouseover event to the makegrid function

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--gridRows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--gridColumns', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = 'grid-item'
  }


  const item = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
  item.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      cell.style.background = 'blue';
    });
  });

}

makeGrid(6, 6);

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let side = prompt('Enter # of squares per side');
  container.replaceChildren();
  makeGrid(side, side);
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--gridRows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gridColumns), 1fr);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
}

#form {
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Project Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="form">Enter number of squares per side for the new grid: </button>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```